# onDataSetChanged() in RemoteViewService is not called after notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged

Tags: android, android-widget

In my AppWidgetProvider class I have the following code inside the `onUpdate()` method:

```
    // Update each of the widgets with the remote adapter
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        HyperLog.i(TAG, "Updating Widget id " + appWidgetId);

        ...

        HyperLog.i(TAG, "Starting updateAppWidget with id " + appWidgetId);
        appWidgetManager.notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetId, R.id.lvActiveReminders);
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, rv);
    }
    super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
```

But the call `notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged()` does not call the RemoteViewService Class method `onDataSetChanged()`:

```
        HyperLog.i(TAG, "onDataSetChanged is called.");
        getData();
```

Does anyone hava a hint why it is not called?

The **onUpdate()** inside AppWidgetProvider is always called and the updateAppWidget refreshes the widget, but with the old data because `onDataSetChaned()` is not called before.
As of the docs this is the way how we should refresh the data of the widget (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/collections#keep-data-fresh).

I am testing this on an Android 12 device.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of tests on different models of smartphones with different Android versions during 2 months I've made the conclusion **the problem is in the OS update from manufacturer**.

**Because**:

1). My smartphone OnePlus 8T with Android 12 had no the problem, like yours, till the last OS update dated by May, 2022. After installing this last update I have the same problem you described: my widgets are updated, but listview of the widgets doesn't not updated very often - onDataSetChanged doesn't start.

2). The same smartphone OnePlus 8T with Android 12 from my friend, **but without last update from May, 2022**, has no any problems with onDataSetChanged - listview is updated, everything works 100% stable.

3). On Samsung with Android 12 there is no any problems: onDataSetChanged reacts on NotifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged.

4). On smartphones with Android 10, 11 onDataSetChanged works stable.

Also I've tested other widgets with listview from other app developers: they updated the listview absolutely stable on Android 12 of my OnePlus before last OS update. After update the analog widgets caught the same problem - onDataSetChanged doesn't start after notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged...